# can I wire a ceiling fan to a 4 DP toggle switch?

Tags: switches, fan, position

I want to re-purpose a ceiling fan motor and would like to have each of the three speeds available on their own switch (or position on a toggle). Is this possible? and if so how should I go about this?

Thanks All!!

Comment: Have you looked at the fan motor yet?

Comment: I have not yet disassembled the fan, no.

Answer (score 1):

There is, in general, two types of ceiling fan motors: those that have multiple taps from the stator windings *or* those that have a single stator winding with several capacitor values that can be switched in series with that winding.

This is most easily done with a rotary switch.

Comment: Hmm, here is where I show how little I know, the fan motor has a single capacitor (a separate square unit) and is controlled by a pull chain so I would think that is a rotary switch. Does any of that sound right or help at all?